# jQuery trigger anchor click action with seperate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, theory

*This is more of a hypothetical question.*

I am wondering if anyone knows if/how it is possible to trigger the click event on an anchor by clicking on another element with jQuery.

My obvious solution, I suppose, would be to grab the content of the `src` on the anchor then js navigate to that location. Unfortunately, the anchor is a `mailto`.

This seems like a bit of a fudge. Is there any other (*more elegant*) way to simulate the user clicking on the anchor by clicking on say a button instead?

The link would look something like: -

```
<a id="testAnchor" href="mailto:test@stackoverflow.com">Email test</a>
```

Comment: Nope. Browsers disable this on purpose as a security measure. However, you can set `window.location` to produce the same result without actually triggering a click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a button like:

```
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Click Me!" />
```

Then you could simulate the click on the a tag by doing:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickme").click(function() {
    document.location.href=$("#testAnchor").attr('href');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked beaut for me too thanks man, window.location navigates away from the page which would be fine for users who want to navigate to the anchor link but as I wanted to open a mailto document.location works a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**No,** you can't do so. But you can do following:

```
window.location = $('#testAnchor').attr('href');
```

Above code will act like trigger click.

You can try with bind a click event with link and then trigger that click.

```
$('#testAnchor').click(function() {
   window.location = this.href;
});
```

Then trigger click:

```
$('#testAnchor').click();
```